# Style of pagination php

Tags: php, pagination

I have an pagination code:

```
//pagination

$result1=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM product");
$row_per_page=10 ; 
$rows=$result1->num_rows;
if ($rows>$row_per_page) $page=ceil($rows/$row_per_page);
else $page=1; 
if(isset($_GET['start']) && (int)$_GET['start'])
    $start=$_GET['start']; 
else 
    $start=0;
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM product limit $start,$row_per_page"); 

//End pagination

while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
   echo $rows['name'];
}

$page_cr=($start/$row_per_page)+1;
for($i=1;$i<=$page;$i++)
{
     if ($page_cr!=$i) echo "<div class='pagination'>"."<a href='index.php?go=product&start=".$row_per_page*($i-1)."'>$i&nbsp;</a>"."</div>";
     else echo "<div class='pagination'>".$i." "."</div>";
}
```

This code create pagination like this
[image: Pagination]

Yeah, i want to remove 6 7 8 9 ect... and replace with "...". When i click to page 6, it will remove 1 2 3 4 5 - 10 11 12 13 etc..,it only show 6 7 8 9 as image below
[![Pagination][2]][2]

[image]

I hope you can understand my ideal, i try the best to show you. 
Thank you so much

Comment: You need to be more specific with the logic. It all seems arbitrary. When you're at page 1 you're showing 5 pages from the start and 4 pages from the end. When you're at page 6 you're showing 4 pages (starting from page 6) and 4 pages from the end. Is there any rule governing this? Any spec?

Comment: You just need some math checks like `if($i > $page_cr+5)`...

Comment: I'm edit my post to make you clear. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's **a solution** to your pagination problem, the kind of solution Google uses to paginate it's search results. Basically, the idea behind this solution is this:

At any point of time, at most 5 pagination links will be displayed i.e. from the current page's perspective, display two predecessor and successor pages. Let me explain this thing using two scenarios,

**Case(1): When the number of pages is equal to or less than 5 (Lets say we have 4 pages)**

In this case, we have to display all pagination links without any preceding or succeeding dots, like this:

```
// User is on page 1
1 2 3 4
  - - -

// User is on page 3
1 2 3 4
- -   -

// User is on page 4
1 2 3 4 
- - -
```

**Case(2): When the number of pages is greater than 5 (Lets say we have 10 pages)**

In this case, we have to display both the pagination links and dots accordingly, like this:

```
// User is on page 1
1 2 3 4 5 ...
  - - - -

// User is on page 5
... 3 4 5 6 7 ...
    - -   - -

// User is on page 10
... 6 7 8 9 10
    - - - -
```

So after getting the current page number using `$page_cr=($start/$row_per_page)+1;`, **the algorithm** of this custom pagination system would be like this:

1. Check whether the number of pages is greater than 5 or not. If it's greater than 5, go to step 2 otherwise go to step 5.
2. Find the superset range of pages, like 1-10, or 1-20 etc. For example, if `$page = 10` then this superset range would be 1-10. The code for this step is this:

   ```
   // Superset range of pages
   $superset_range = range(1, $page);
   ```
3. Find the subset range of pages to display, like 1-5, or 3-7 etc. For example, if `$page = 10` then this subset range would be 1-5, or 3-7, or 6-10 etc., it can be any consecutive five page between 1 and 10. Also, adjust this range whenever necessary. The code for this step is this:

   ```
   // Subset range of pages to display
   $subset_range = range($page_cr - 2, $page_cr + 2);

   // Adjust the range
   foreach($subset_range as $p){
       if($p <= 0){
           array_shift($subset_range);
           $subset_range[] = $subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] + 1;
       }elseif($p > $page){
           array_pop($subset_range);
           array_unshift($subset_range, $subset_range[0] - 1);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Display the pagination links and dots accordingly. The code for this step is this:

   ```
   // Display pagination links and dots
   if($subset_range[0] > $superset_range[0]){
       echo "<div class='pagination'>...&nbsp;</div>";
   }
   foreach($subset_range as $p){
       if($page_cr != $p){
           echo "<div class='pagination'>"."<a href='index.php?go=product&start=".$row_per_page*($p-1)."'>$p&nbsp;</a>"."</div>"; 
       }else{
           echo "<div class='pagination'>".$p." "."</div>";
       }

   }
   if($subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] < $superset_range[count($superset_range) - 1]){
       echo "<div class='pagination'>&nbsp;...</div>";
   }
   ```
5. Display all pagination links using your old code, like this:

   ```
   // Display all page links
   for($i = 1; $i <= $page; $i++){
       if($page_cr != $i){
           echo "<div class='pagination'>"."<a href='index.php?go=product&start=".$row_per_page*($i-1)."'>$i&nbsp;</a>"."</div>"; 
       }else{
           echo "<div class='pagination'>".$i." "."</div>";
       }
   }
   ```

So here's **the complete code:**

```
$result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM product");
$row_per_page= 10; 
$rows=$result1->num_rows;

if ($rows > $row_per_page){ 
    $page=ceil($rows/$row_per_page);
}else{
    $page=1;
}
if(isset($_GET['start']) && (int)$_GET['start']){
    $start=$_GET['start']; 
}else{
    $start=0;
}
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM product limit $start,$row_per_page"); 

while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
   echo $rows['name'];
}

$page_cr=($start / $row_per_page) + 1; // Page number

if($page > 5){
    // From the current page's perspective, display two predecessor and successor pages 

    // Superset range of pages
    $superset_range = range(1, $page);

    // Subset range of pages to display
    $subset_range = range($page_cr - 2, $page_cr + 2);

    // Adjust the range
    foreach($subset_range as $p){
        if($p <= 0){
            array_shift($subset_range);
            $subset_range[] = $subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] + 1;
        }elseif($p > $page){
            array_pop($subset_range);
            array_unshift($subset_range, $subset_range[0] - 1);
        }
    }

    // Display pagination links and dots
    if($subset_range[0] > $superset_range[0]){
        echo "<div class='pagination'>...&nbsp;</div>";
    }
    foreach($subset_range as $p){
        if($page_cr != $p){
            echo "<div class='pagination'>"."<a href='index.php?go=product&start=".$row_per_page*($p-1)."'>$p&nbsp;</a>"."</div>"; 
        }else{
            echo "<div class='pagination'>".$p." "."</div>";
        }

    }
    if($subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] < $superset_range[count($superset_range) - 1]){
        echo "<div class='pagination'>&nbsp;...</div>";
    }
}else{
    // Display all page links
    for($i = 1; $i <= $page; $i++){
        if($page_cr != $i){
            echo "<div class='pagination'>"."<a href='index.php?go=product&start=".$row_per_page*($i-1)."'>$i&nbsp;</a>"."</div>"; 
        }else{
            echo "<div class='pagination'>".$i." "."</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's realy help me to save time so much. Thank you